# cant load an image to be moved by my keyboard

Tags: java

I have been following some java game development tutorial , and I was able to create an oval shaped object that can move with my keyboard input and created boundaries , however I attempted to replace the oval with an image but for some reason it is not showing up, I'm pretty sure the image I chose is not large , it is more like a small icon and thanks in advance.

```
package javagame;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JavaGame extends JFrame{

int x,y;
private Graphics dbg;
private Image dbImage;
    Font font = new Font("Arial" , Font.BOLD, 30);
    Image face;
public class AL extends KeyAdapter{



    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(KeyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
              if(x<=0)
            x=0;
            else
            x -=15;
        }


         if(KeyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
            if(y>=480)
                y=480;
            else
             y+=5;

        }
          if(KeyCode == e.VK_UP) {
             if(y<=20) 
                y=20;
             else
              y-=5;

          }

           if(KeyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
          if(x>=480)
               x=480;
          else
               x+=5;
        }

}

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

}
}

public JavaGame() {
    //game images
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Sheref/Documents/NetBeansProjects/avaGame/src/javagame/type-of-solder-001-512.gif");
    face = i.getImage();
    //game properties
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setTitle(" Strategy Game");
    setSize(500,500);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        x = 20 ;
        y = 30;

}

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth() , getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage , 0 , 0 , this);
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawImage(face, x, y, this);
    repaint();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new JavaGame();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `paint` method, instead of

```
this.dbImage = this.createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

put:

```
this.dbImage = this.createImage((int) this.getSize().getWidth(), (int) this.getSize().getHeight());
```